# Problem reinstalling Animation Nodes on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: animation-nodes

I had been using animation nodes with Blender 2.92 , version animation_nodes_v2_2_linux_py37.zip . It had been working fine . I left blender and did a cleanup of my system using Bleachbit as I was running out of space on a drive. When I came back Animation Nodes wasn't working. I tried reinstalling it and got the error message below. Any idea what I could have done in cleaning my system to make it not work? Would it be a problem with Python version installed? Below is the error message. Thanks.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/snap/blender/111/2.92/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
mod = **import**(module_name)
File "/home/jim/.config/blender/2.92/scripts/addons/animation_nodes/**init**.py", line 158, in 
raise Exception(message)
Exception:

This build does not work at the moment.

1. Check if the build you downloaded has been compiled for the OS
   you are using. If not, download another one.
2. If you are on windows you can try to install a library called
   'vc_redist.x64'. Should be easy to find using your search engine
   of choice.
3. Try to use an official Blender release downloaded from blender.org.
4. It is possible that you have a build for the correct platform
   but it still does not work. We experienced this mainly on linux.
   Try to find another build for your platform.
   If it still does not work, you have to compile AN yourself.
5. Make a bug report on Github and give as much information
   as you can. Specifically the full error message, your OS, version, ...

EDIT :

I downloaded the latest alpha version of Blender 2.93 and used the version of animation nodes for 2.93 ie. animation_nodes_v2_2_linux_py39.zip . This worked however I am still perplexed why the version for Blender 2.92 didn't work , even after a complete reinstall of Blender 2.92. I prefer not to use an alpha version so still looking for answers as to why 2.92 isn't working with it's version of animation-nodes.

Comment: I am not sure why you used bleachbit to clear space on your hard drive, but not knowing much about the program myself, is it possible you accidentally erased something blender related, such as a necessary piece of software?

Comment: Hi. Please have a look at this report on AN GitHub page: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240#issuecomment-738743294